# cannot write to log file pg_upgrade_internal.log on pg_upgrade

Tags: 13.10, postgresql

I keep on getting the above error whenever I run the following command via a postgres user.

`$ /usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/pg_upgrade -b /usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/bin/ -B /usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/ -d /var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main -D /var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main`

```
cannot write to log file pg_upgrade_internal.log
Failure, exiting
```

I'm using Ubuntu 13.10. Both Postgresql 9.1 and 9.3 are running properly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This usually means that your current working directory is a directory that the `postgres` user can't write to. That's where `pg_upgrade` will try to write to.

Simply change directory to another that it can write to (or edit the current one's to allow other write).

Comment: Thank you Oli, it worked.
Just a note for other users, you might have to copy postgresql.conf from /etc/postgresql/9.1/ to /var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main/ for both versions for upgrade to work. For other errors just check the log file.